# convert string of various format into datetime object

Tags: python

I have a column of dates in string of several different formats: `Feb 02, 1976`, `02-08-2001`, etc. How can I convert them into datetime objects using `strptime`? Is there a way to let `datetime` recognize the format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `datetime.datetime.strptime`, you can use [`dateutil.parser.parse`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse) (third party library [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)):

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> dateutil.parser.parse('Feb 02, 1976')
datetime.datetime(1976, 2, 2, 0, 0)
>>> dateutil.parser.parse('02-08-2001')
datetime.datetime(2001, 2, 8, 0, 0)
```